# Mvc Javascript Not Working

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

In Mvc Javascript Is Not Working Button Click Event
I Want To Raise Button Click Event.

```
<input type="button" id="btn_click" value="Click" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        $('#btn_click').click(function () {
            alert('You Clicked Button');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Please Help me

Comment: did you include appropriate jquery files?  Also, hit F12 for browser tools, reload the page, and try clicking the button again, does the console report any errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This actually has nothing to do with ASP.NET, C# or Razor. This is pure HTML and JavaScript.
You have wrapped the `click` function in `pageLoad` which is not being called.
So you simply have to remove it.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="button" id="btn_click" value="Click" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#btn_click').click(function() {
        alert('You Clicked Button');
      });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For button

```
<input type="button" id="btn_click" value="Click" />
```

**Use javascript as-**

```
function showalert(){
     alert('You Clicked Button');
}    
document.getElementById("btn_click").onclick = showalert;
```

Answer (score 0):

`pageLoad` function is never called hence `event-listener` is never attached!

Either invoke it or just Place your `<script>` as `last-child` of `<body>`(Just before closing body tag(`</body>`))

```js
$('#btn_click').click(function() {
  alert('You Clicked Button');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn_click" value="Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`pageLoad` function not call, but if you want to call it after pageload you can use `$(function(){})` like that

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn_click').click(function () {
        alert('You Clicked Button');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wra the click event in a function , but button click does not call that function.

You can call this function `onClick` event of button

```
<input type="button" id="btn_click" value="Click" onClick="pageLoad()" />

function pageLoad() {
  alert('You Clicked Button');
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/bvh53y3s/)

Answer (score 0):

Put your Javascript code in **document ready**.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {       
        $('#btn_click').click(function () {
            alert('You Clicked Button');
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="btn_click" value="Click" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function btnclick() {
  alert('You Clicked Button');
};
```

```html
  <input type="button" id="btn_click" value="Click" onclick="btnclick();" />
```